# How to include full stacktrace in the zabbix email alert.

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have configured monitoring zabbix server 3.4.2 for wildfly monitoring using http-remoting also monitoring wildfly logs, is it possible to include full stacktace in the alert email.

Item: log[{$LYCHEEMCR_LOG_FILE},WARN,UTF-8,100]

Trigger : {Template App Wildfly:log[{$LYCHEEMCR_LOG_FILE},WARN,UTF-8,100].nodata(30)}=0

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix does not know the concept of stacktraces yet - or, in a more generic way, it does not know the concept of multiline log entries. This would have to be extracted in some other way than using Zabbix agent - then, if the whole stacktrace was stored as a single item value, it could be included in the alert.

Comment: Shall we try something  regex matching lines, I just saw the thread https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1428

Comment: That's a feature request asking for multiline log entry support. I don't see anything sane being achievable with regexps.